# Convert plain english to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, nlp

What would be the best way I could convert english text to sql queries.  For example, if I wanted a user to run a query by typing in "show me college students with a GPA higher than 3." or "show mothers with 2 or more kids"  The closest link I found so far is this: http://english2sql.com/demo.html, but it does not look like it is supported much since the email I sent them bounced back to me.  If there are some open source libraries I could use for this, preferably in C# that would be awesome.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You are aware that this is a difficult thing to do even for Google? If you define a grammar the user input has to comply to it must be doable/not too hard though...

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).  _Some data included!_

Comment: There have been attempts to do this for many years.  However, it seems that plain English is not a very good way to return formatted results to users.  In my opinion, you are better off trying to design a user interface that meets your user needs, and not try to parse natural language queries.

Comment: I would take an *easier* way such as QBE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example , http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dbbook/openAccess/thirdEdition/qbe.pdf with a good UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com) project.
It has very interesting abilities to parse and tokenise sentences.
Once you have a stream of tokens you can analyse and construct other "sentences" from it, for example in SQL.

Say, you can recognize verb tokens like "show", "display" and know that it is going to be a SELECT query, then you find a noun and treat it as a table name, a preposition like "with" will become "WHERE", article tokens could be ignored, etc.

Here is an example of how it can tokenise a sentence, recognize a type of every token and much more: [Parsing English Sentences](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12109/Statistical-parsing-of-English-sentences)

Also you may look at the [M language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd285271.aspx) which is a DSL modeling language from Microsoft (I saw it presented on one of PDCs). It would probably a bit easier to use it than things like SharpNLP as you can easily define your own grammar rules so it will understand phrases like "show me mothers with more than 2 kids" and will know exactly what to do with them.
But I have no idea of what is the state of M-language now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you will face is converting a loose grammar (English) into a strict grammar (SQL), for example: "Get me all records regarding parents whose kids go to high-schools.", "Show me parents whose kids are in high-schools", "Let me see parents who have kids in highschools."

all of these statements might resolve to SQL...

```
SELECT * FROM Parents WHERE AttendsHighSchool = 1;
```

To build this natural language to query system, you are delving into the realms of artificial intelligence. You might want to consider building a UI which builds the SQL query based on certain parameters,

i.e.

```
"Show me " [DropDown containing tables] 
where [DropDown containing Arguments] [DropDown containing operators] [DropDown containing values] "
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Kueri.me](http://kueri.me), a platform that converts plain English to SQL. 
It is capable of understanding user input even when it is provided in different forms.

For example,

- Show me college students with GPA higher tha 3
- Students with GPA higher than 3
- GPA > 3

The platform comes out of the box ready with basic filtering, grouping and ordering. 
You can further configure the tables to get additional language coverage.

For example, you might want to enable geo-location, like

- show me students from Detroit with GPA bigger than 3
- show me students from NYC within 20km

Or define verbs

- show me students that registered last year and attended more than 30 lessons

Please note, I am from Kueri.

Answer (score 2):

Try [FriendlyData](https://friendlydata.io/) API. It accepts plain English and produces SQL statement or returns JSON-object with the data from your databae